# One user can't open a folder in explorer view, others can

Tags: 2007, error, webdav, registry

I have an issue where one user is currently unable to open a folder (the folder has ~40,000 8kb-12kb XML files within it) in explorer view.

I believe this could potentially be being caused by limits with webdav. I found the following article which I believe is related (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900900).

My question is - Under the resolution I'm told to update the values at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters - Is this done client or server side (I would check but I'm a BA so I need to open a ticket to have registry changes made so this is my first port of call)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all client related, so registry fixes (hacks) should be done to the client machine.

I tend to avoid over emphasis on the Explorer view.  It is not going to work consistently for a wide range of users based on devices, browsers, and installed software which tends to lead to more support issues.

Comment: I wish that were an option however it's used quite heavily throughout the business (enough so that it's not possible to break away from it now). Thankfully we've only had two instances where this has been an issue in three years despite having 500+ users so it doesn't appear to cause too many problems overall.

Comment: @Michael be sure to advocate for robust testing before any changes are made to the versions of the OS, Office, or browser.  I've seen it breaking when changing any of those things.  If any users start to use Chrome, FireFox, or Safari things change as well.